# How to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, redirect

I have looked around and I can't seem to find a definitive solution for this. We are having a small problem with a few or our visitors that are typing in our domain as such:

`https://www.example.com` - This is giving a security warning "There is a problem with this website's security certificate."

We have an SSL set up for `example.com`

So if someone types in `http://www.example.com` or `www.example.com` this gets redirected to `https://example.com` which works fine.

This is what I have currently have in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace the last `RewriteCond` line with this one? `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*) [NC]`

Comment: @JCoder Thanks for the replies. I will implement this now and let you know what happens.

Comment: @JCoder. Just tried this and did not work. Thanks for your help. I would suggest taking your comment below and and answer this question and I will approve. Thanks!

Comment: But you say that it did not work?!

Comment: Evidently I am slow because I seem to be the only one that cannot discern what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:**

Most SSL certificates are issued for a specific hostname, e.g. `www.example.com` or just `example.com` (and there can be wildcard certificates for `*.example.com` too) so this might be the case.

<strike>Maybe making the **www.** subdomain an *optional match* in the last `RewriteCond` might help to get the user to the domain stated in the certificate:</strike>

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*) [NC]
```

Comment: Right this trick didn't work. What I was referring to was the comment you made earlier. Under the Eugene post. "Most SSL certificates are issued for a specific hostname..."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Besides editing my answer I also tried the change on my own server and it looks like that the www. was removed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not with the rewrite/redirect rules but simply with the way http servers handle ssl connection. Before even server has a chance to look into rewrite/redirect rules the SSL handshake take place and if we have a cert for example.com and we enter URL www.example.com connection will abort due to invalid certificate. Check for yourself, set up redirect condition to point URL www.example.com to example.com on SSL secured domain. At first you'll get invalid cert error, but when you add an exception to your browser you'll notice that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]+$
RewriteRule !"" https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Could the person who placed -1 also explain himself?

Comment: @Eugene I tried this just now and I am still getting the same warning. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Could it be that the SSL is only securing domain.com and not www.domain.com?

Comment: Most SSL certificates are issued for a specific hostname, e.g. www.domain.com or just domain.com (and there can be wildcard certificates for *.domain.com too) so this might be the case.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't that case and that there would be a work around this.

Comment: I've added a comment for the first posting, maybe that helps to remove the www. for all requests.

Comment: @jCoder Yep. You're right. Didn't thought about that. The certificates do contain the specified domain name in the encryption if I'm correct. So it's probably that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. If a user accesses www.domain.cc over SSL, then you will get a certificate error if you do not have a valid SSL certificate - even if all you want to do is redirect them to the correct site.

You will either need a new certificate for www.domain.cc, or convince your registrar to give you a wildcard certificate for *.domain.cc, or one with multiple subjectAltName properties. See http://www.crsr.net/Notes/Apache-HTTPS-virtual-host.html

Or ask for SNA http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will need an SSL certificate that covers both `www.xxxx.yyy` and `xxxx.yyy`.
Your provider may cover both if you get the cert for `www.xxxx.yyy`, but only the `xxxx.yyy` if you get it for that. Read their conditions carefully.

I had read so many suggestions as to how to redirect, with all manner of ad-hoc opinions, with varying results, and mostly without any formal explanation.

Of course, that means going to the Apache `.htaccess` reference and working from first principles was in order.

Just to reiterate, the main requirement is to redirect all http(s) requests to `https://xxxx.yyy`.

As always, turn the rewrite engine on:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

For http, that is:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxx.yyy/$1 [L,R]
```

However, doing the same for https (port = 443), will force a loop, which bombs out with an error. We have to restrict the process to only working for the `https` and `www`. We do this by providing two `RewriteCond` statements in a row, which are treated as an implicit AND:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www[.].+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxxx.yyy/$1 [L,R]
```

At the end of the `RewriteRule`, the `[L,R]` tells the rewrite engine to:

1. `L` = stop at that rule. That is, if a rule is executed because its conditions (`RewriteCond`) were satisfied, stop when done, else go to the next conditions/rule set.
2. `R` = issue a HTTP redirect (default code = 302) to the browser, so user or automatic action can be taken to update bookmarks, so they always use the `https://xxxx.yyy` in future.