# Redirect https://*.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

### Request:

My certificate does not allow for wildcards and only applies to `https://example.com`.

I want to redirect all traffic from: `http(s)://*.example.com` <kbd>--></kbd> `https://example.com`.

### Problem:

This works fine going from `http://*.example.com/*` to `https://example.com/*`

I get the error **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** when going from:

`https://*.example.com/*` to `https://example.com`.

### What I have tried so far...

This is my `default.conf` configuration file for the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        NameVirtualHost *:80
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        NameVirtualHost *:443
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        Redirect permanent "(?i)https:\/\/\d*[a-z0-9]*.example.com" "https://example.com"
```

I have tried several variations of the last Redirect line above, as suggested in several related questions. I can only post two at this time since I'm new here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781718/redirect-http-https-www-to-https-domain-com-using-htaccess
- [How to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779533/how-to-redirect-https-www-domain-com-to-https-domain-com)

I'm guessing that this is not working because the server returns a certificate error before processing the Redirect code. One of the questions I linked to above hints at that, but it was not accepted as an answer and no one really confirms or denies it.

### My Question (finally!):

Is it possible to do this without having a wildcard certificate? If so, what's wrong with my Redirect code above? As far as I can tell, the regex is working for a case-insensitive redirect from `https://*.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this without having a wildcard certificate?

No. The reason why is because you have a cert that says the only hostname that is valid is **example.com**, and the first thing that happens is a connection to the webserver is made and the SSL handshake is established. This handshake happens before any HTTP communication takes place. That means, during the handshake, the browser is given the certificate, which says "you should only be talking to **example.com**" and the browser sees that it just attempted to connect to "**www.example.com**", and the browser stops right there and returns the exception that you see. This exception doesn't originate from the server, it's the browser saying something's not right.

Since all of this happens before any HTTP communication is even made (since it has to be encrypted, and you can't encrypt until the handshake is established), there is **nothing you can do** as far as mod_rewrite or redirecting from apache, because Apache hasn't even received the request yet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll up that vote count once I'm above 15 points :)  Wish there was some way to pass this info along with TLS or DNS.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

add above code in your .htaccess file
your url will be redirect like: 
https://www.example.com/test  to -> https://example.com/test

Comment: I replaced `Redirect permanent "(?i)https:\/\/\d*[a-z0-9]*.domain.com" "https://domain.com"` with your rewrite code and I am still getting the same error when trying, for example, `https://foo.domain.com`. It doesn't redirect to `https://domain.com` and gives this error: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589282/force-https-www-domain-to-https-domain  exactly your solution

Comment: Thanks. That person's question can be addressed by issuing a new cert that allows both www and not-www. Many providers add the optional www SAN to their certs now. An option I also have with my cert, but I want *.domain.com not just www.domain.com to redirect. Seems my only solution is a wildcard cert as @jon-lim explained above.